# Silverstripe 3.7 Unit Tests - tearDownOnce() and setUpOnce() do not trigger

Tags: silverstripe

Silverstripe 3.7.6, PHP 7.3, PHPUnit 4.8

We have a bunch of existing unit tests that use SapphireTest->setUpOnce() and SapphireTest->tearDownOnce(). The latter is used to destroy test databases once complete. Which is how we found that these methods were not firing.

Simple test that simulates

```
<?php

class MyTest extends SapphireTest {

    protected $usesDatabase = true;

    public function setUp()
    {
        echo "setup \n";
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        echo "teardown \n";
        parent::tearDown();
    }

    public function setUpOnce()
    {
        echo "setup once \n";
        parent::setUpOnce();
    }

    public function tearDownOnce()
    {
        echo "teardown once \n";
        parent::tearDownOnce();
    }

    function testSomething()
    {
        // My test
    }

}
```

Output when test is run:

> PHPUnit 4.8.36 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> .setup  teardown
>
> Time: 6.38 seconds, Memory: 80.50MB
>
> OK (1 test, 0 assertions)

Is there something that needs to be done in the test so these functions are fired at the start and end of the whole test class per docblock?

**UPDATE:**

See convo below. It was suggested that I use PHPUnit's setUpBeforeClass and tearDownAfterClass methods instead. These fired as expected. However they are static methods so I had no access to $this to use supporting SapphireTest or custom methods in the class. So I had to use these PHPUnit methods to instantiate an instance of the test class they sit in, then call my existing setUpOnce and tearDownOnce methods. I used [late static binding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)'s static() keyword here as I might move these calls into a parent class for my tests all to use. A bit hacky, but it seems to work.

Assuming my test code above, below is the addition to make:

```
public static function setUpBeforeClass() {
    $object = new static();
    $object->setUpOnce();
}

public static function tearDownAfterClass() {
    $object = new static();
    $object->tearDownOnce();
}
```

Comment: Are all tests green? I once found, that when tests are failing, the DB isn't destroyed. There is afaik a buildtask to remove the orphaned test databases.

Comment: I'd probably rely on PHPUnit's internals for this rather than what SapphireTest gives you, e.g. `setUpBeforeClass` and `tearDownAfterClass`

Comment: @wmk Yes all tests are green. Even then neither setUpOnce nor tearDownOnce seem to trigger.

Comment: @robbie-averill thanks, those two do trigger. However since they are static they don't have access to $this for accessing methods inside SapphireTest. So I had to use these methods to create an instance of the test class, then call the respective setUpOnce and tearDownOnce methods I already had. A bit roundabout, but it works. I'll update my question with detail. Cheers.